# Derivative of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I've been doing pretty well with derivatives but I don't know how to find the derivative of the following function:

$f(x) = e^{-x^2}$

Comment: $$y=e^{-x^2}$$ $$\ln y=-x^2$$ $$\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-2x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that $(g\circ f)'=(g'\circ f)\cdot f'$, in this case $f=-x^2$, $f'=-2x$, $g=e^x$, $g'=e^x$, so
$$\bigl(e^{-x^2}\bigr)'=e^{-x^2}\cdot(-2x)$$

Answer (score 3):

given $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ by the chaine rule we obtain $$f'(x)=(-2x)e^{-x^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you need to compute the derivative of $$f(x)=e^{g(x)}$$ Take the logarithm of both sides to get $$\log\big(f(x)\big)=g(x)$$ Now, compute the derivatives; so $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=g'(x)$$ and then $$f'(x)=f(x)\space g'(x)$$ which is the same as the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the expression to one of the patterns you're familiar with.

Commonly, the simplest approach is to look at the outermost operation first -- that is, if you actually plugged in numbers, look at the operation you would compute last. In this case, you would first compute the value of $x^2$, and lastly you would "raise $e$ to the power $x^2$".

The last step was raising $e$ to the power $x^2$: that means you should look at the derivative laws for exponentiation: the two simplest cases you know are

- The derivative of $g(x)^n$ is $n g(x)^{n-1} g'(x)$
- The derivative of $a^{g(x)}$ is $g'(x) a^{g(x)} \log a$

Or in dependent variable notation,

- $\frac{d}{dx} u^n = n u^{n-1} \frac{du}{dx}$
- $\frac{d}{dx} a^u = a^u \log a \frac{du}{dx}$

where $n$ and $a$ are constants.

One of these patterns matches the problem you're given. For example, if your problem was to differentiate $(x^2 + 1)^3$, you would observe it's of the first pattern. To make things match, you would set $u = x^2 + 1$ and $n = 3$, and write

$$ \frac{d}{dx} (x^2 + 1)^3 = 3 \cdot (x^2 + 1)^{3-1} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (x^2 + 1) $$

Then you would repeat the process to compute the new derivative on the right hand side.

Now, maybe your derivative tables are simplified; e.g. maybe it only has

$$ \frac{d}{dx} x^n = n x^{n-1} $$

You can always take one of these simplified entries and use the *chain rule* to produce the more useful entry. We switch the variable to $u$:

$$ \frac{d}{du} u^n = n u^{n-1} $$

and then the chain rule tells us

$$ \frac{d}{dx} u^n = \frac{d}{du} (u^n) \cdot \frac{du}{dx} $$